# Why do we specify strings in string.xml

Tags: android, string

Is there really a need to specify strings in an XML file. Android always shows warning when strings are directly written and not extracted from strings.xml. Is there any advantage by using XML

Comment: The main advantage of using string.xml file is you have to specify your strings once and use it anywhere throught the app.If any change made in that particular string you have to change once.And one imp thing is localization to write the string in multi language.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important use is ***to handle localization***.

*At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.*

*For example, the following are some different string resource files for different languages.*

- English (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

> ```
> <string name="title">My Application</string>
> <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
> ```

- Spanish, /values-es/strings.xml:

> ```
> <resources>
>    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
>    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
> </resources>
> ```

- French, /values-fr/strings.xml:

> ```
> <resources>
>     <string name="title">Mon Application</string>
>     <string name="hello_world">Bonjour le monde !</string>
> </resources>
> ```

*In your source code, you can refer to a string resource with the syntax R.string.. There are a variety of methods that accept a string resource this way.*

```
// Get a string resource from your app's Resources
String hello = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);

// Or supply a string resource to a method that requires a string
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

From [Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

---

Read [Localizing with Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for details, and [Android Localization Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_localization.htm) is a very good tutorial about the same.

Comment: I have some questions. If I have two string.xml file one for french and other for english. Does the app or the android system use the appropriate string file. And under what condition(s)?

Answer (score 4):

We added string on strings.xml, because we can easily translate our whole app into other languages.

So in the folder values you would have strings.xml with this content:

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
```

In values-fr a strings.xml with this content:

```
<string name="hello">Bonjour</string>
```

If you want to make your application support different - 2 language than you have to follow string.xml.